# If condition doesn't work in javascript/jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, conditional-statements

I have a list of products displayed in `DataList` in `asp.net`. I have a `TextBox` in `DataList` containing products which contains the `Price`. This `Textbox` is used to modify the `Price` of the product. I want to display the Message to the user only if the the `Price` Entered by the user is `LESS THAN` the `Minimum` price set to the Product using `JQuery/Javascript`.

All works fine. Just when i validating the TextBox using `Class` name it works for the First `TextBox` Only in the `DataList` and not for remaining `TextBox`(when i enter amount 10 in `TextBox` (considering minimum price is 50) it must go to 'if' part of script. But, it goes to 'else' part in script) in the DataList. i.e the LESS THAN symbol works only for the FirstItem in `DataList` and not for Other `TextBox`.

**In Content Tag:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       // $(".numericText").change(function() {alert("changecalled") });

        $(document).on("change", ".numericText", function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var sp = $(this).attr("sp");
            var mp = $(this).attr("mp");
            //var changedVal = $("#" + id).val();
            var changedVal = $("#"+this.id).val();
            if(changedVal < mp)
            {
                alert("Minimum Price of this Product is: " + mp);
                $("#" + id).focus();
                //return false;
            }
            else {
                alert("Price OK: " + changedVal + " mp:" + mp);
                //return true;
            }
            //alert("ind doc" + "\n" + "SP:" + sp + " " + "MP" + mp + "CV:" + changedVal);

        });
</script>
```

**In DataList Item Template:**

```
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSalesPrice"  class="numericText" sp='<%# Eval("SalesPrice") %>'
    mp='<%# Eval("MinimumPrice") %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SalesPrice") %>'
    Width="60px"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="BtnDevices" runat="server" class="btnCart" Text="Add to Cart" CommandName="AddToCart"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' />
</p>
```

**Note: 
DataList is in UpdatePanel. I have also checked using ALERT it shows values correct what i entered but dont know why 'LESSTHAN" symbol fails to evaluate?**

Dont know why?

Any Idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `parseInt` to your values. because java script take those value to string, So the condition got this problem

The `Javascript` compile the code look like

```
if("10" < "9"))
    {

//codes
```

So those values are string, and the condition could failed

You need to juts change the if condition to

```
if(parseInt(changedVal) < parseInt(mp))
{
// codes
```

Comment: hey @Ramesh Rajendran! yes it works fine..!thanks :D

Comment: oops, I did' see your post, when i typing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(parseInt(changedVal) < parseInt(mp))
{
    alert("Minimum Price of this Product is: " + mp);
    $("#" + id).focus();
    //return false;
}
else {
    alert("Price OK: " + changedVal + " mp:" + mp);
    //return true;
}
```